# c#, using visual studio 2012 ,able to save to database but cannot update

Tags: c#, sql-update, insert-update, system.data.sqlite

Below is the code I wrote, so please check it and tell what is wrong.
I have posted the insert and update code here.

I have learned this from youtube so I don't know every detail about a database so please post in a language an amateur like me would understand

```
 public void bsave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
        SQLiteConnection sqliyeCon = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnectionString);
        //open connection to database
        try
        {
            sqliyeCon.Open();
            string Query = "insert into employeeinfo (name,surname,age) values('" + this.name.Text + "', '" + this.surname.Text + "' , '" + this.age.Text + "')";
            SQLiteCommand createCommand = new SQLiteCommand(Query, sqliyeCon);
            createCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Data is saved succesfully");
            sqliyeCon.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
 }

 private void bup_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
        SQLiteConnection sqliyeCon = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnectionString);
        //open connection to database
        try
        {
            sqliyeCon.Open();
            string Query = "update employeeinfo set eid='" + this.eid.Text + "' , name ='" + this.name.Text + "',surname='" + this.surname.Text + "', age='" + this.age.Text + "' where eid=eid='" + this.eid.Text + "' ";
            SQLiteCommand createCommand = new SQLiteCommand(Query, sqliyeCon);
            createCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Updated");
            sqliyeCon.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand that you learned this from youtube, but you should try reading about this as well. Currently, you're exposing your data layer on your front end's code behind (you should have this extracted to a separate project), as well as exposing sql injection attacks (you're placing user inputs directly into your query). It's really dangerous and very bad practice.

Comment: Plz tel me how to do that,thanx for telling about probable injection chances...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"' where eid=eid='"` should be `"' where eid='"`

```
string Query = "update employeeinfo set eid='" + this.eid.Text + "' , name ='" + this.name.Text + "',surname='" + this.surname.Text + "', age='" + this.age.Text + "' where eid='" + this.eid.Text + "' ";
```